# Testing socket.io events

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I'm working on a nodejs application. I managed to break some of the code in separate modules, that I'm testing using nodeunit, but a substantial part of my code base still relies on socket.io.

How can I test my socket.io events?

Comment: Was the linked article sufficient, or have you opted for a different approach?

Comment: Thanks for asking. The article looks ok, but I'm not entirely sure this is the way to go. As far as I can tell the link you provided tests what the server is sending, but the logic in my code actually does a lot of stuff in the backend which is not immediately visible to the clients. As I mentioned, I moved some of it into stand alone modules, but there are still some parts that are untested which I'm afraid will fail silently when I least expect them sometime in the unforeseen future. So while I can still make the solution you provided me work, I feel that there's an awful lot of work needed.

Comment: Sounds like a good candidate for Jasmine's Spies - answer updated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this article: [Socket.IO and Asynchronous Testing with node.js](http://nullzzz.blogspot.com/2011/03/socketio-and-asynchronous-testing-with.html).

> So, let's fake. I mean, let's create fake instances of the contender
>   servers, as well as the visualization client. Then, we'll build a test
>   suite that uses these fakes to test-drive the actual server we're
>   developing. I'll paste some slightly simplified pieces of code here
>   for example. If you are really interested in the stuff, you'll find it
>   all on [Github](https://github.com/reaktor/competition).

**edit:** if you need to test functionality for which there is no immediate output, Jasmine BDD provides [spies](https://github.com/pivotal/jasmine/wiki/Spies). These can be used to "see inside" a function and test whether certain parameters are passed etc, and are useful for mocking asynchronous calls for testing, as well as writing more functional tests:

> Jasmine Spies are test doubles that can act as stubs, spies, fakes or
>   when used in an expecation, mocks...Spies can be checked if they were
>   called or not and what the calling params were. A Spy has the
>   following fields: wasCalled, callCount, mostRecentCall, and
>   argsForCall (see docs). Spies are torn down at the end of every spec.

[Docs](https://github.com/pivotal/jasmine/wiki/Spies), [an article](http://a-developer-life.blogspot.com/2011/06/jasmine-part-2-spies-and-mocks.html) and a [related SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4662641/how-do-i-verify-jquery-ajax-events-with-jasmine).