# Jasmine and Jquery, loading a JSON file

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, coffeescript, jasmine

I have the following method to load a JSON file using coffeescript/jquery:

```
Class JsonParser

this.return  = (json_file_path, string_to_query) ->
  $.getJSON json_file_path, (data) ->
    $.each data, (key,val) ->
     if key == string_to_query
       return val
```

And I am Testing it in Jasmine with:

```
expect(JsonParser.return("file.json", "key").toEqual("value")
```

But what Jasmine spits out instead is:

```
Expected { readyState : 1, getResponseHeader : Function, getAllResponseHeaders
 : Function, setRequestHeader : Function, overrideMimeType : Function, statusCode : Function, abort : 
Function, state : Function, always : Function, then : Function, promise : Function, pipe : Function, d
one : Function, fail : Function, progress : Function, complete : Function, success : Function, error :
 Function } to equal 'value'.
```

Assume the JSON file has only one line: `{ "key": "value" }`

I am just getting my feet wet with jquery/coffeescript/ajax etc. and don't understand Jasmines response. Let me know if further information is needed thanks!.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that your `return` method doesn't return what you think it does. Your `return` function returns what [`getJSON`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) returns and `getJSON` is an AJAX call. jQuery's AJAX calls all return [`jqXHR`s](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#jqXHR) and that has nothing to do with what the AJAX callbacks return. The sequence of events looks something like this:

1. You call `JsonParser.return`.
2. `return` calls `$.getJSON`.
3. `getJSON` makes an asynchronous call to the server and then returns a `jqXHR`.
4. `return` returns the same `jqXHR` that `getJSON` returns.
5. Some time passes.
6. The server gets around to responding and your callback is called to search through the JSON.

The problem is that while **(5)** is happening, the code that called `JsonParser.return` is still going but it has no JSON.

The usual way to get around the asynchronous nature of AJAX calls is to send in a callback function that will get called when something is ready:

```
@return: (json_file_path, string_to_query, callback) ->
  $.getJSON json_file_path, (data) ->
    $.each data, (key,val) ->
     if key == string_to_query
       callback(val)
```

Then you'd use it like this:

```
JsonParser.return("file.json", "key", (value) ->
  # Do whatever needs to be done with value in here.
)
```

Now you have something that should work and you can find out how to use Jasmine with it over here:

> [How do I verify jQuery AJAX events with Jasmine?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4662641/479863)

Comment: Thanks for the response, I am still getting the same result, the json file path I have been using is a local file, not called through a server, is that potentially an issue ?

Comment: @Discorick: You can't do AJAX without a server and you can't use normal Jasmine techniques to test AJAX.