# Going deep into jasmine spy

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, bdd, jasmine

I want to ask somthing about jasmine spy . Normally i use spy like this

```
function getAuthrize(id) {
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/Account/LogOn" + id,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json"
});
}
spyOn($, "ajax");
getAuthrize(123);
expect($.ajax).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

but i want to know that what if i want to validate more things like ( the `url` called in ajax call is `/Account/LogOn`, `type is 'Get'` and so on .

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check if a spy was called with specific parameters you an use `toHaveBeenCalledWith` like this:

```
expect($.ajax).toHaveBeenCalled({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/Account/LogOn" + id,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json"
});
```

But this will be become a very hard to read error when only one field in the JSON is wrong.

Another way is to use `mostRecentCall.args`:

```
var args = $.ajax.mostRecentCall.args[0];
expect(args.type).toEqual('GET')
expect(args.url).toEqual('/Account/LogOn123')
```

This will lead in a better readable errors as you can see which paramater was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

For that you need to use a fake server object

Something like `sinon.fakeServer`

```
describe('view interactions', function(){
    beforeEach(function() {
        this.saveResponse = this.serverResponse.someObj.POST;
        this.server = sinon.fakeServer.create();
        this.server.respondWith(
              'POST',
               this.saveResponse.url,
               this.validResponse(this.saveResponse)
        );
    });

    afterEach(function() {
     this.server.restore();
    });
});
```

Need to make sure you have the `this.serverResponse` object defined

Comment: i am not using `sinon` is there any way to do this in core `jasmine` ?

Comment: I have not worked with jasmine on ajax requests. Maybe this should be of help .. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4662641/how-do-i-verify-jquery-ajax-events-with-jasmine