# Trouble Using AngularJS $httpBackend to respond to BreezeJS executeQuery

Tags: angularjs, breeze, httpbackend

Has anyone been able to build specs or e2e tests using $httpBackend while having BreezeJS function as your entity manager?

Here is the BreezeJS code:

```
function getClientsAll() {
    var query = breeze.EntityQuery.from('clients').using($clientJsonResultsAdapter);        
    return em.executeQuery(query);
}
```

And here is the test code from the Jasmine Spec using AngularJS $httpBackend:

```
it('should show all clients', function() {
    $httpBackend.expectGET(/clients/).respond([ 200, mockData.clients.GET]);
    backupModelService.getClientsAll()
        .then(function() {
            console.log("getClientsAll success");
        })
        .fail(function() {
            console.log("getClientsAll fail");
        })
    $httpBackend.flush();//error thrown here
});
```

But I get the jasmine test failure

```
Error: No pending request to flush !
```

This breeze method works fine running in the browser but not during tests. However, if I convert to using angularJS $http or $resource, this test will pass.  I'm wondering if BreezeJS is not compatible with the $httpBackend for spec and e2e testing.

Thanks for any insight.

//EDIT --- AFTER TRYING TO MOCK AJAX BECAUSE OF STEVE'S RESPONSE

This fails as well.

```
    var success = jasmine.createSpy('success');
    var fail = jasmine.createSpy('fail');
    spyOn($, 'ajax').andCallFake(function (req) {
        var d = $.Deferred();
        d.resolve(mockData.clients.GET);
        return d.promise();
    });
    backupModelService.getClientsAll()
        .then(success)
        .fail(fail);

    expect(success).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

Answer (score 1):

Breeze does not use Angular's $http or $resource for sending XHR.  It uses jQuery's AJAX implementation.  So queries performed using `em.executeQuery(query)` will not go through $httpBackend.

When testing using Breeze, you should spy/stub/mock jQuery's $.ajax, as described in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4662641/how-do-i-verify-jquery-ajax-events-with-jasmine).

Comment: Steve, thanks for the response.  I'm still not getting breeze to execute the call for some reason.  I'm going to edit my response to include the changes you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

That's not fully true. Breeze added an ajax adapter for $http in v.1.4.4
This is the way to setup the ajax adapter

```
function configBreeze($q, $http) {
    // tell the adapter to use your app module's $http for ajax calls

    var ajax = breeze.config.initializeAdapterInstance('ajax', 'angular');
    ajax.setHttp($http);
}
```

After this you will be able to use $httpBackend on your tests

More info here
http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/customizing-ajax
and here 
[Breeze using angular $http interceptor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21327238/breeze-using-angular-http-interceptor)