# Jasmine not recognizing my (global) functions

Tags: javascript, ajax, function, jasmine, jasmine-jquery

First time using Jasmine, still trying to get a handle on things. Using 2.0.0 standalone version. I've got the following lines in my SpecRunner.html:

```
//... jasmine js files included here ...
<!-- include source files here... -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jasmine-jquery.1.3.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="src/admin.js"></script>
//... the rest of my scripts, and then my specs ...
```

So I am definitely including my admin.js file, in which I declare the following set of functions:

```
$(function() {
    function deleteLink(linkHref, callback) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/delete?href=" + linkHref,
            success: callback
        });
    }

    function redirectHome() {
        location.assign("/");
    }

    $('.delete_button').on('click', function() {
        var buttonUrl = $(this).parent().data('link-href');
        if( confirm("Are you sure you want to remove this link?") ) {
            deleteLink(buttonUrl, redirectHome);
        }
    });
});
```

I'm trying to test this functionality (which works in the browser exactly as I expect it to) with the [suggested format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4662641/how-do-i-verify-jquery-ajax-events-with-jasmine) for testing AJAX callbacks:

```
describe("Admin library", function() {
    describe(".delete_button event handling", function() {
        beforeEach(function() {
            loadFixtures("delete_button.html");
        });

        // other tests here...

        it("should set the location to /", function() {
            spyOn($, "ajax").and.callFake(function(e) {
                e.success();
            });
            var callback = jasmine.createSpy();
            deleteLink("http://some.link.href.com", callback);
            expect(callback).toHaveBeenCalled();
        });
    });
});
```

However, the test always fails with this error:

```
Can't find variable: deleteLink in file:///path/to/my/app/jasmine/spec/adminSpec.js
```

I'm currently testing functions in other jasmine/spec files that aren't declared explicitly in those files. I thought that was the point of including the scripts in the SpecRunner.html file, right? Any ideas as to what's going on here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `deleteLink` function is not global. It's declared inside a [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures) (in your case it's a self calling function). If you want to have that function global, you need to add this in your "admin.js" file inside the closure :

```
window.deleteLink = deleteLink;
```

Comment: Dude you are awesome. I'm still getting the hang of closures, myself, so I was completely duped by this error. Mind helping me in the right direction, if this is the "right way" to handle situations like these? Or is the goal of a javascript developer to avoid making these global functions? I couldn't think of a useful JS object to instantiate to which I could assign this function, so I went with the simplest option I saw...

Comment: @BradRice If a method needs to be used elsewhere it needs to be public. What you want to avoid is to have global variable or function that shouldn't be accessed by other files. Also, if your project gets bigger, you can "namespace" those function in object like `window.MyNamespace = {}` and `window.MyNamespace.MyFunction = ...`.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. For anyone like me, who wanted a bit more information as to what makes methods and properties "public" vs "private" vs "privileged", I found this article to be very helpful: http://phrogz.net/JS/classes/OOPinJS.html