# using jasmine to mock ajax requests

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, unit-testing, jasmine

I am currently trying to test my javascript code using jasmine. It has been ok until now where i need to mock ajax requests. I currently use jasmine 1.2 and mock-ajax.js My code is as follows:

I have a handler.js file which basically has a number of ajax requests. I am using require.js which to read the config js file which has the relevant urls.

```
define(['urlConfig'], function (urlConfig) {
    return {
        getAllCustomers: function () {
            return $.ajax({
                url: config.url,
                dataType: 'json',
                xhrFields: {
                    withCredentials: true
                },
            });
        }
}
```

So basically i have now created a spec to test to see if the ajax requests do get hit.

```
define(["/../dependencies/squire.js"], function(Squire) {
    var injector;

    beforeEach(function() {
        injector = new Squire();
        jasmine.Ajax.install();
    });

    describe("handler", function() {
        var mockData = {
            data: [
                {
                    reference: "ref1",
                    name: "bob"
                },
                {
                    reference: "ref2",
                    name: "fred"
                }
            ]
        }


        function loadModule() {
            mockHandler();
        }


        function mockHandler() {
            injector.mock('handlers/Handler', {
                getAllCustomers: function() {
                    return {
                        then: function(callback) {
                            callback(mockData);
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        };

        describe("get all customers", function() {
            beforeEach(function() {
                loadModule();

            });

            it('expect to get all account details on request', function() {
                spyOn($, "ajax").andCallFake(function(options) {
                    options.success();
                });

                var callback = jasmine.createSpy();

                mockHandler().getCustomerDetails(callback);
                expect(callback).toHaveBeenCalled();
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Not sure if the above is correct but also getting an error stating **TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'spyOn($, "ajax").andCallFake(function(options)**

Any help would be greay

Answer (score 2):

The function `.andCallFaketo()` changed to `.and.callFake()` in version 2.0 of Jasmine. Like this example:

```
spyOn().and.callFake(function() {
        return 1001;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need help mocking jQuery ajax calls check this question:

[How do I verify jQuery AJAX events with Jasmine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4662641/how-do-i-verify-jquery-ajax-events-with-jasmine)

It helped me.

Comment: Just consider that the selected answer is outdated and wont work with versions > 2.0